# C++ Directive With void(0)

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the purpose of having a directive like below?

```
#define TEST_CONDITION(con) !(con) ? (void)0:
```

In particular, I see this called at the start of other directives.

For example,

```
#define OTHER_CONDITION(..)
  TEST_CONDITION(someFunction)
  ANOTHER_DIRECTIVE(...)
```

Doesn't `TEST_CONDITION` just no-op or a boolean is returned that isn't used in these cases?

Comment: You chopped so much out of the example that I can't make any sense out of it.

Comment: This is something to put then you dont need to put anything. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert macro

Comment: This code is not even legal C++ if `ANOTHER_DIRECTIVE` does not expand to something of type `void`, making this entire macro mess some sort of obfuscated and restricted `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Expand the macro, and it becomes clearer. I'll also use some formatting to keep the code readable, and I assume that the lack of some essential escape characters is not meant to be part of the example. `OTHER_CONDITION` becomes:

```
!(someFunction)
    ? (void)0
    : ANOTHER_DIRECTIVE(...)
```

So, the expression `someFunction` is executed, and if it is `true`, then `ANOTHER_DIRECTIVE(...)` (or whatever it expands to) is executed. Otherwise nothing is executed.

---

Simpler way to write `OTHER_CONDITION` could be:

```
#define OTHER_CONDITION(..) if(someFunction) ANOTHER_DIRECTIVE(...)
```

This simplification lacks some restrictions that `TEST_CONDITION` provides:

- `TEST_CONDITION` makes it impossible to append an `else` branch.
- `TEST_CONDITION` makes it ill-formed to use a non-void `ANOTHER_DIRECTIVE(...)`.

Comment: There will be no "result returned" as one of the operands having type `void` (other than a throw expression) forces the other operand to be of type `void`, too, yielding `void` as final result type. In particular: "then 0 is returned without side-effects" No, that will not happen.

Comment: @BaummitAugen you're right. To clarify, is this correct: third operand must be void (possibly a throw expression), or else the expression is ill-formed?

Comment: Third operand must be of type `void`, which includes throw expressions. Complete rules [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). Edit: After you edited your comment, it's correct.